# Is there a way to disable the harmful website warning in Chrome for a single website?

Tags: google-chrome

I like to visit kat.cr and even though it might contain links to harmful websites (which are probably supressed by my adblocker anyway), the site itself works great and I would like to disable the red screen warning that I get each time. Is this possible?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcPbQ.png)

[Security report](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/index.html?hl=en-GB#url=http://kat.cr/)

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Because I don't have the same experience with that website and using Chrome.

Comment: Works fine for me too. Are you sure it's not your Anti-virus giving you that warning?  Can you provide a screen shot of the error?

Answer (score 0):

In the **top-right corner** of the browser window, click the **Chrome menu.**

- Select Settings.
- Click Show advanced settings.
- Under "Privacy," uncheck the box "Protect you and your device from
  dangerous sites."

*P.S-This article on [TorrentFreak](https://torrentfreak.com/kickasstorrents-blocked-again-over-harmful-programs-151021/) might help you with why chrome is acting this way and it's not possible to do this for specific website its chrome's build in feature either you follow the rules set by it or create your own. If you still want to access kat.cr you can go [torrentsum](http://torrentsum.com) it's another url for the site. Hope this resolves your issue!!!Cheers!*

Comment: Except the author wants to disable it for a single website not every website.

Comment: This article on [TorrentFreak](https://torrentfreak.com/kickasstorrents-blocked-again-over-harmful-programs-151021/) might help you with why chrome is acting this way and it's not possible to do this for specific website its chrome's build in feature either you follow the rules set by it or create your own. if you still want to access kat.cr you can go [torrentsum](torrentsum.com) it's another url for the site. Hope this resolves your issue!!!Cheers!

Comment: So indicate that it isn't possible.  I provided a comment before I voted.  Give me a reason to press up instead of down.

Comment: That's additional information that's why it is below the answer!!

Comment: Comments are not permanent.  If its additional information it should be in your answer.  Just indicate its additional information.

Comment: Yeah either you say with certainty that it can't be done or you provide a solution. This doesn't resolve my issue at all. Not accepting the answer.